# DocuSign account cannot get JWT token

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have two accounts of DocuSign, both have the same config on the Setting section. But the first one even though expires of the trial still can send the envelopes. The second one gets invalid_request when I tried to get the JWT token base on ***client_id***, ***user_id***, and ***private_key***.

Do we need to enable some config to allow it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Are you using a **trial** (login via [www.docusign.net](http://www.docusign.net)) or **developer demo** account (login via demo.docusign.net)? You should only use **developer demo** accounts while developing with DocuSign.
2. To get a free developer demo account click the link at the top right of the [developer center](https://developers.docusign.com) page. Demo accounts do not expire, but their envelopes that are over 30 days old are automatically deleted.
3. `invalid_request` can be cause by a number of different issues. Additional information is available in the **body** of the response. Please see what it is and then edit your question to add the information.

### Added

For JWT `invalid_request` errors, the recommended steps are:

1. Get the DocuSign code example running with JWT grant. For C#, [this repo](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp).
2. Once that works, you'll know that the problem is in your code, not in the settings of the integration key (the client id), the private key, etc.
3. Check that your computer's clock settings are correct--the timezone and the day/date. These are used by JWT.
4. Check that you are specifying a user's guid id to be impersonated. This is also referred to as a user's "API User Id"
5. Check the body of the API response for additional debugging information.
6. If you receive the error "consent_required", that is *good* news since it indicates that your JWT grant was correct, except that the person being impersonated hasn't yet granted consent to be impersonated. To fix, see this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent).

Comment: thanks, for 1 and 2 I used the developer demo (sandbox account)... I will double check the body and update you soon.

Comment: as I checked.. the content of response is Invalid_request :(

Comment: all of the code is correct... i did use the sample code, it work well with one of my account.. then I just change the key of the second one and it throw invalid_request

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "change the key of the second one" If you still can't figure it out, email go-live@docusign.com

Comment: the second one means the second account of mine... what is the content of the email? do you have any template, Larry?